# How to decode a JSON string in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that looks something like this:

```
{"addresses":{"address":[{"@array":"true","@id":"888888","@uri":"xyz","household":{"@id":"44444","@uri":"xyz"},"person":{"@id":"","@uri":""},"addressType":{"@id":"1","@uri":"xyz","name":"Primary"},"address1":"xyz","address2":null,"address3":null,"city":"xyz","postalCode":"111111"}]}}
```

What would be the PHP to decode this and place `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `city`, and `postalCode` into session variables?

So far I tried this but it's not working:

```
$results = json_decode(strstr($address, '{"addresses":{"address":[{'), true);
$_SESSION['address1'] = $results['address']['address1'];
```

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't happening that you want to happen? Always describe the behavior you want and the behavior you get.

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` before outputting anything and before referencing $_SESSION?

Comment: So many answers... so few question upvotes.

Comment: Many answers often means easy question, not *good* question.

Comment: Easy for some but not others, hence the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`print_r` is your friend for figuring out JSON structure.

```
<?php

$addresses = json_decode('{"addresses":{"address":[{"@array":"true","@id":"888888","@uri":"xyz","household":{"@id":"44444","@uri":"xyz"},"person":{"@id":"","@uri":""},"addressType":{"@id":"1","@uri":"xyz","name":"Primary"},"address1":"xyz","address2":null,"address3":null,"city":"xyz","postalCode":"111111"}]}}');

$_SESSION['address1'] = $addresses->addresses->address[0]->address1;
$_SESSION['address2'] = $addresses->addresses->address[0]->address2;
$_SESSION['address3'] = $addresses->addresses->address[0]->address3;
$_SESSION['city'] = $addresses->addresses->address[0]->city;
$_SESSION['postalCode'] = $addresses->addresses->address[0]->postalCode;

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [address1] => xyz
    [address2] => 
    [address3] => 
    [city] => xyz
    [postalCode] => 111111
)
```

Comment: +1 To print the results nicely as displayed, add the <pre> tag after the print_r(). This one took me forever to figure out!

Comment: AWESOME!!!!  Thank you very much, this did it.  I negelected to mention that I was using strstr because I had some other header information contained in $addresses and needed to chop it out.  But this did the job and I'm very grateful!!!

Answer (score 3):

[json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) will decode a json-formatted string into a PHP *object*.

Try this:

```
$results = json_decode($address);
$results['address1'] = $results->addresses->address[0]->address1;
$results['address2'] = $results->addresses->address[0]->address2;
$results['address3'] = $results->addresses->address[0]->address3;
$results['city'] = $results->addresses->address[0]->city;
$results['postalCode'] = $results->addresses->address[0]->postalCode;
```

Edit - updated, I misread your JSON at first.

Answer (score 2):

Note that those "@array" and "@id" fields are invalid JSON notation, and technically they lead to unspecified behavior in JSON parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not decode the whole JSON string and then get what you need?

```
$address = '{"addresses":{"address":[{"@array":"true","@id":"888888","@uri":"xyz","household":{"@id":"44444","@uri":"xyz"},"person":{"@id":"","@uri":""},"addressType":{"@id":"1","@uri":"xyz","name":"Primary"},"address1":"xyz","address2":null,"address3":null,"city":"xyz","postalCode":"111111"}]}}';
$results = json_decode($address, true);
$address = $results['addresses']['address'][0];
print $address['address1'];
print $address['address2'];
print $address['postalCode'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try $results['addresses']['address']['address1'];

Not sure why you're using strstr. but it doesn't look like it'd change anything in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use print_r to output the $results to find out exactly what the object output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you do print_r of your array, you see how the layout is:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [addresses] => stdClass Object
    (
      [address] => Array
        (
          [0] => stdClass Object
            (
              [@array] => true
              [@id] => 888888
              [@uri] => xyz
              [household] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [@id] => 44444
                  [@uri] => xyz
                )

              [person] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [@id] => 
                  [@uri] => 
                )

              [addressType] => stdClass Object
                (
                  [@id] => 1
                  [@uri] => xyz
                  [name] => Primary
                )

              [address1] => xyz
              [address2] => 
              [address3] => 
              [city] => xyz
              [postalCode] => 111111
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

json_decode($jsonData) returns an object btw, not an array.

For example:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [addresses] => stdClass Object
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@array] => true
                            [@id] => 888888
                            [@uri] => xyz
                            [household] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@id] => 44444
                                    [@uri] => xyz
                                )

                            [person] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@id] => 
                                    [@uri] => 
                                )

                            [addressType] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [@id] => 1
                                    [@uri] => xyz
                                    [name] => Primary
                                )

                            [address1] => xyz
                            [address2] => 
                            [address3] => 
                            [city] => xyz
                            [postalCode] => 111111
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Ways to access data:

```
$object = json_decode($jsonString);
$object->addresses->address[0]; // First address object
$object->addresses->address[0]->{"@array"}; // Not good way to access object property (damn @)
$object->addresses->address[0]->address1;
$object->addresses->address[0]->addressType->{"@id"}; // Again damn @
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will put *all* scalar and null values into session where key does not begin with a @

```
$jsonString = '{"addresses":{"address":[{"@array":"true","@id":"888888","@uri":"xyz","household":{"@id":"44444","@uri":"xyz"},"person":{"@id":"","@uri":""},"addressType":{"@id":"1","@uri":"xyz","name":"Primary"},"address1":"xyz","address2":null,"address3":null,"city":"xyz","postalCode":"111111"}]}}';

$result = json_decode($jsonString);

// will put *all* scalar and null values into session where key does not begin with a @
foreach($result->addresses->address[0] as $key=>$value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 1) != '@'  && (is_scalar($value) || is_null($value)) ) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    } 
}

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```