# Extract/decode variable from JSON string

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode a JSON string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268792/how-to-decode-a-json-string-in-php)

I would like to extract the variable `'name'` from the json string `$jsonstring`;

```
<?php

$facebookid = $_GET['fbid'];
$facebooklink = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookid.'?fields=name';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $facebooklink);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

`$jsonstring` would output something like the following:

```
{
   "name": "THIS PART IS WHAT I WANT",
   "id": "4"
}
```

I would like to extract the 'this part is what i want' from the above example.

I have tried using json_decode but couldn't get it working, I have since deleted that code and therefore cannot write it here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);` will not give you assign of json. It just gives you status of `curl_exec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
ob_start();
$facebookid = $_GET['fbid'];
$facebooklink = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookid.'?fields=name';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $facebooklink);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$bufferstr = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$json = json_decode($bufferstr);
echo $json->name;
```

Comment: @Andreas & OP - Thanks for the replys - However every answer returns the same thing:
{"name": "THIS PART IS WHAT I WANT","id": "4"}
without the 'name' extracted, I don't know what I'm doing wrong? :s
Thanks.

Comment: @Harry  any error? any output echoing or doing `var_dump`?

Comment: I know its a lot to ask, but you would be doing me a massive, massive favour if you could quickly look over my code? I'd be extremely grateful,
I have uploaded the .php file to here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2578642/facebookconf.php
Thank you

Comment: @Harry It was because `$jsonstring` didn't give you content of json. It is just status that `curl_exec` was success. Look at my edited post. I use buffer to catch the json string.

Comment: I thank you so, so much! Its working now - you've helped me out greatly! Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
  $foo = json_decode( $jsonstring);
  $name = $foo->name; 
  //echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$json_obj = json_decode($jsonstring );
echo $json_obj->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you do not have "json_decode" in your php version you should use a regular expression.

```
<?php

$name = json_decode( $jsonstring )->name;

?>
```