# I need transform string to array

Tags: php

I have string variable. It can be:
    $string = '["image11.jpg"]';
Or:
    $string = '["image11.jpg","image54.png"]';
Or:
    $string = '["image11.jpg","image54.png"]';
Or:
    $string = '["image11.jpg","image54.png","dfgr.rar"]';
And so on.
I need this variable as array, for example:
    $arr[0] = 'image11.jpg';
Or:
    $arr[0] = "image11.jpg";
    $arr[1] = "image54.png";
Or:
    $arr[0] = "image11.jpg";
    $arr[1] = "image54.png";
    $arr[2] = "dfgr.rar";
And so on.
Is there optimal code for that?

Comment: `json_decode($str, TRUE)`.

Comment: Did you come up with that format yourself or is that ***JSON***?

Comment: json from javascript (jquery, ajax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode a JSON string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268792/how-to-decode-a-json-string-in-php)

Comment: json_decode($str, TRUE) - I dont't know why, but it works on localhost, and don't work on hosting server. That's why I decided to transform string myself.

Comment: Then you should try to fix that problem. What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: Worst case, should your production server be running such an old version of PHP that it doesn't come with `json_decode`, there's the http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/ polyfill to replace that function. But if your PHP version is *that* old, you have other problems to worry about. Don't try to reinvent a JSON parser yourself, try to fix the existing solutions if they're not working!

Comment: "Don't try to reinvent a JSON parser yourself, try to fix the existing solutions if they're not working!" - ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = '["image11.jpg","image54.png"]';
$arr=json_decode($string);
echo $arr[0];
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work on hosting server. And it works on my localhost (denwer). I don't know why...

Comment: I havn't access to php.ini in my server, but if I echo phpinfo(), json is enabled (not json_decode, I don't know about json_decode).

Comment: That would return an object, not an array.

Comment: Please, contact to administrator..Because here is working ..You can test online on "http://codepad.org/"

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php json_decode will return an associative array if the optional second parameter 'assoc' is true.

Answer (score 2):

use `json_decode` for make this string to array

```
$arr = json_decode($string,true)
```

thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
preg_match_all('@"(.*?)"@',$string,$arr);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the explode() function.

For example

```
$string = ' "image11.jpg","image54.png","dfgr.rar" ';
$arr = explode(',',$string);  //separating string using coma ',' character
```

In above example, the $arr table will consists of 3 values;

```
$arr[0] ="image11.jpg";
$arr[1] ="image54.png";
$arr[2] ="dfgr.rar";
```