# Read associative array from json received from $_POST

Tags: php, json, post

i have a php file receive $_GET informations AND $_POST information, for the $_GET information no problem with that so for the $_POST information i receive this string :

```
[{"channel":"\/meta\/handshake","id":"10","minimumVersion":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["websocket","long-polling"],"version":"1.0"}]
```

with [ to start and ] to end.

so how can i read this ? thank you for helping !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode a JSON string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268792/how-to-decode-a-json-string-in-php)

Comment: Is the string under a specific name in $_POST?

Comment: No i know the function json_decode(); ! the problem is other, read bellow ! thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [json_decode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$channels = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // parse raw post
print_r($channels) // print structure of channels
```

Comment: Oh !!!! @Ric you're a King ! with put://input now i see the string on $channels. Thank you very much for your answer and help ! Have a great day !!!

Answer (score 1):

first decode the `json` data like this

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST,true);
```

then access the data like this

```
echo $arr[0]['channel']; // output "/meta/handshake"
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZeI9n3

Comment: i try your code:$arr = json_decode($_POST, true); and i received this : Warning:json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /staging/websync/client.php on line 77. On firebug i see this on Console Post : JSON 
0 Object { channel= "/meta/handshake", id="1", minimumVersion="1.0", supportedConnectionTypes=["websocket"
, "long-polling"], version="1.0"}

Source
[{"channel":"\/meta\/handshake","id":"1","minimumVersion":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["websocket","long-polling"],"version":"1.0"}]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str  = '[{"channel":"\/meta\/handshake","id":"10","minimumVersion":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["websocket","long-polling"],"version":"1.0"}]';


echo "<pre>";
$arra   = json_decode($str,true);
print_r($arra);
/*Uncomment this for your out put*/
//echo "Required : ".echo $arra[0]['channel'];
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [channel] => /meta/handshake
            [id] => 10
            [minimumVersion] => 1.0
            [supportedConnectionTypes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => websocket
                    [1] => long-polling
                )

            [version] => 1.0
        )

)
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Yeah this code is working and i know this code, the problem is wen i try to read the data receive from $_POST.

Comment: When i try code : $arr = json_decode($_POST, true); I received this : Warning : json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /staging/websync/client.php on line 77. So, on firebug i see this on Console Post : JSON 
0 Object { channel= "/meta/handshake", id="1", minimumVersion="1.0", supportedConnectionTypes=["websocket"
, "long-polling"], version="1.0"}

Source
[{"channel":"\/meta\/handshake","id":"1","minimumVersion":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["websocket","long-polling"],"version":"1.0"}]

Comment: YOU SHOULD NOT GIVE IT LIKE THAT, because $_POST is an array, $arr = `json_decode($_POST['your_post_variable'], true);`