# Extract JSON from HTML source and use it

Tags: php, html, json

I have a URL like http://example.com - The HTML source of it is:

```
<html>
test
test2
{"customer":{"email":null,"is_eu":true"}
t
</html>
```

I want to get the JSON only from it then get anything from this JSON

My current code is here:

```
$whole_html = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("http:/example.com"));
preg_match('~\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}~', $whole_html, $json);
$JsonResults = print_r($json, true);
$json_decoded = json_decode($JsonResults, true);
echo $json_decoded['customer']['email'];
```

But the result is empty page.

***EDIT***: The result of `echo print_r($json, true)` is:

```
Array ( [0] => {"customer":{"email":null,"is_eu":true} )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a JSON string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268792/how-to-decode-a-json-string-in-php)

Comment: Your HTML code isn't valid. If you must store JSON inside your HTML document, make sure to put it inside an element, such as a `<div id="my-JSON">`. But why don't you store the file directly as `myfile.json`? Is there any specific reason for storing it as an HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json string in the example html code above is incorrect. It must be like this

{"customer":{"email":null,"is_eu":true}}

You can use the following code.

```
$whole_html = file_get_contents("http:/example.com");
preg_match('~\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}~', $whole_html, $json);
$arr = json_decode($json[0],true);
$email = $arr['customer']['email']; 
$is_eu = $arr['customer']['is_eu'];
```

Comment: And how can I extract the value of "email" using this? Should I set the last line of your code in a variable? @Meskan